# Does the sequence of characteristic functions converge uniformly?

Tags: uniform-convergence

$f_n(x) = 1$ if $x ∈ [0, \frac{1}{n}$] and $f_n(x) = 0$ otherwise. I know that it converges pointwise. My guess is that it doesn't converge uniformly since lim $sup (f_n(x)) = 1$ as n goes to $\infty$. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

It converge pointwise to $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x=0\\ 0&otherwise\end{cases}.$$

Now, $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\chi_{]0,1/n]}(x).$$
Therefore, for all $n$, $$\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|=1,$$
and thus, the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Thanks! So what I thought was correct then?

Comment: The fact that $\limsup_{n\to \infty }f_n(x)=1$ is wrong since the limsup depend on $x$. For example, for $x=2$, $\limsup_{n\to \infty }f_n(x)=0$.  And actually, for every $x\neq 0$, $\limsup_{n\to \infty }f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty }f_n(x)=0$.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand. Isn't sup $|f_n(x)-f(x)| = 1$? Doesn't that mean that its limit won't tend to 0 and will be 1?

Comment: Yes, $\sup_{x\in \mathbb R}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=1$ (as I showed). But what is the relationship with $\limsup_{n\to \infty }f_n(x)=0$ ?

Comment: Doesn't that mean its limit is always 1 and not 0? so the limit of sup as n goes to infinity would be 1 right?